# Magento Admin Create and Save HTML to Database With a Form Field

Tags: html, magento

I am working on a module that requires some html to be entered to be later called upon and become part of a customer facing widget output.

I've created an administrative backend and that is all working properly, however when I enter html into the field that should be storing the data i receive an error. 
I dont need the wysiwyg but I would like to be able to enter html into this value.

At this point I've not done anything special when adding the field to the fieldset. What am I missing?

```
    $contentField = $fieldset->addField('inner_html', 'editor', array(
        'name'      => 'inner_html',
        'style'     => 'height:36em;width:36em',
        'required'  => false,
    ));
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: It turns out that I was handling the unique id incorrectly in the controller. It had nothing to do with html parsing, Its built right into the core classes. I'm going to detail some aspects shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$fieldset->addField('inner_html', 'editor', array( 
    'name' => 'inner_html', 
    'label' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Description'), 
    'title' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Description'), 
    'style' => 'width:700px; height:350px;', 
    'config' => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(array('add_variables' => false, 'add_widgets' => false,'files_browser_window_url'=>$this->getBaseUrl().'admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/')), 
    'wysiwyg' => true, 
    'required' => false, 
));
```